# Hiding in plain sight

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

[image: Which word is hiding in this maze?]

Look closely at this piece of abstract art. A word is hidden in plain sight...

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Would I be right in guessing that you're affiliated with the "Codex Enigmatum" thing mentioned under the puzzle? If so, please take a look at https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4340/how-not-to-be-a-spammer-redux which has some advice on PSE's norms around promotional stuff.

Comment: In this case, the big notice at the bottom is frankly too much, and makes this as much an advertisement as a puzzle. That's not really what PSE is for. I've cropped it out, but if you want to add some _text_ explaining where the puzzle comes from -- and disclosing your affiliation, if any! -- then that would be fine. (More than fine: there *should* be some such text. But I couldn't add it and be sure of getting it right, because e.g. I don't know whether the puzzle is actually in the book.)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you

> draw a straight line through each of those narrow gaps between black blocks

it looks like the word

> [image]

Comment: Ahh, this reminds me of the time when I was trying to make a decoration using a plank of wood and lasers.